# Draggable circle in swing blinks when I drag it

Tags: java, swing

I'm implementing a Swing program that draws shapes to the screen and then lets the user drag them around. I can draw a shape just fine, but once I click on a shape to drag it, that shape starts to blink as it is dragged.

This is my GUI class and my MouseAdapter class:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {
    private JMenu addShapeMenu = new JMenu("Add Shape");
    private JLabel statusBar = new JLabel();
    private List<Shape> _shapes;
    private Shape chosenShape;
    private boolean isShapeClicked = false;
    private List<String> shapeSubclasses = new ArrayList<>();

    public GUI() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        super("DrawingBoard");
        setSize(500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        menuBar.add(addShapeMenu);

        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        getLoadedShapes();
        for(String shape : shapeSubclasses)
        {
            Class drawableShape = Class.forName("gui.Drawable" + shape);
            addShapeMenu.add(((DrawableShape)drawableShape.newInstance()).getInstance().getMenuItem());
        }

        add(statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        statusBar.setText("Add a shape.");

        MouseHandler mouseHandler = new MouseHandler();
        addMouseListener(mouseHandler);
        addMouseMotionListener(mouseHandler);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics graphics)
    {
        super.paint(graphics);
        for(Shape shape : _shapes)
        try
        {
            Class painter = Class.forName("gui.Drawable" + shape.getClass().getSimpleName());
            ((DrawableShape)painter.newInstance()).getInstance().paint(getGraphics(), shape);
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Failed to load Drawable" + shape);
        }
    }

    private class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter implements MouseMotionListener {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
            _shapes.forEach(shape -> {
                if(shape.isPointInside(event.getX(), event.getY()))
                    chosenShape = shape;
                isShapeClicked = true;
            });
        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
            if (isShapeClicked) {
                chosenShape.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                repaint();
            }
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
            isShapeClicked = false;
                chosenShape = null;
        }
    }
}
```

where my DrawableCircle class has a method paint:

```
public void paint(Graphics graphics, Shape shape)
    {
        int radius = ((Circle)shape).getRadius();
        graphics.fillOval(shape.getX() - radius, shape.getY() - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
    }
```

the DrawRectangle class is similar.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Loading class within the `paint` method is not a good idea, as this  could take valuable time which could cause a delay to the screen been updated

Answer (score 2):

- Loading class within the `paint` method is not a good idea, as this  could take valuable time which could cause a delay to the screen been updated
- DON'T override `paint` of top level container, they are not double buffered.  Instead, create a custom component, extending from something like `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method, placing your custom painting into to (don't forget to call `super.paintComponent` first).

See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details

Comment: I moved my paint methods to a JPanel's paintComponent and everything worked fine. Thanks.